# No permission to write to serial device

Tags: 14.04, bash, permissions, serial-port

Getting error "`Permission denied`" while writing to serial port from command line. I do :

```
echo aaa > /dev/ttyS0
```

or even

```
sudo echo aaa > /dev/ttyS0
```

but get the same result. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it by adding the current used to `dialout` group. Run:

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER
```

Then log off and log on.

After that you will be able to write to serial devices without `sudo` permissions.

If you do not want to give permanent permissions for serial devices, you can use a correct command:

```
echo aaa | sudo tee /dev/ttyS0
```